Does the factor of 4 in assembly row offset calculation come from the size of integers?

I am analyzing a nested array access code in assembly, where the array contains integers. The machine code calculates the row offset for accessing a specific subarray. Here's what I have observed:

Each subarray contains 5 integers. Since an integer is 4 bytes, the row offset for accessing the index-th subarray is 20 * index.
In the leaq instruction, this calculation is broken down as 4 * (index + 4 * index).

From my understanding, factor 4 seems to be related to the size of an integer (4 bytes). However, I am unsure if this interpretation is correct. Specifically:

If the subarrays had 6 integers instead of 5, the row offset would become 24 * index. If we were to break this down while accounting for the size of integers, would the 4 still appear in the breakdown because integers are 4 bytes?

I want to confirm whether the 4 in such assembly calculations is always tied to the size of the array elements (in this case, integers). If so, how would the assembly breakdown change for arrays of different element sizes or subarray sizes?
For example, in subarrays of size 6, we can have something like this:
# %rdi = index
movq %rdi, %rcx          # Copy %rdi (index) to %rcx
salq $1, %rcx            # Left shift %rcx by 1 to compute 2 * index
leaq (%rcx, %rdi, 4), %rax  # Compute 6 * index using 2 * index + 4 * index
leaq pgh(,%rax,4), %rax     # Compute pgh + (24 * index)

OR
# %rdi = index
leaq (%rdi, %rdi, 2), %rax  # Compute 3 * index
leaq pgh(,%rax,8), %rax     # Compute pgh + (24 * index)



Didn't read but: 4 * (index + 4 * index) is just another way to write 20*index. If an array element has size T, each element is at offset 0, T, 2T, 3T, ... That's enough to understand every case, including an array of array (with fixed size, just find out the sub array size first).

@MargaretBloom My query is regarding how the compiler handles this offset while generating the assembly code (x86-64). Does it need to account for element size (here integer) when calculating these memory offsets (refer to solution 1) or just find the best factors (refer to solution 2)?

Yes, C array[i] is an element offset, like assembly [array + rdi*4].  Assembly only works with byte offsets; either increment the pointer by 4 to move to the next element (if they're 32-bit), or if incrementing an actual i in a register, the scale it when using it as an index.  The scale factor in addressing modes works well for this, and was obviously intended to support it.

@PeterCordes My primary concern is whether the assembly implementation depends on finding the best addressing mode (e.g., scaling factors like 1, 2, 4, 8) or accounting for element size explicitly. Check my two approaches for reference.

The second one is obviously better, just two LEAs being more efficient, with addressing modes that differ only in the scale factor (but using non-zero shift counts for both).  Address math is just integer math, the final result being equal is all that matters, not how you get there.  It makes no difference whether one of the operations scaled by 4.


My query is regarding how the compiler handles this offset while generating the assembly code ... Does it need to account for element size (here integer) when calculating these memory offsets

Yes, it needs to account for element size (here sizeof(integer)=4).

or just find the best factors

Yes, that works as well, if the best factors incorporate the size of each element.

My primary concern is whether the assembly implementation depends on finding the best addressing mode (e.g., scaling factors like 1, 2, 4, 8) or accounting for element size explicitly. My primary concern is whether the assembly implementation depends on finding the best addressing mode (e.g., scaling factors like 1, 2, 4, 8) or accounting for element size explicitly.

Yes, the element size must be accounted for in the arithmetic for indexing into an array.
However, best is somewhat subjective (i.e. varies by processor, sometimes by performance vs. space, by instruction count/size), but no, assembly does not require best — why would it?
It doesn't require best, only accurate.  Any approach that accurately accomplishes the arithmetic behind indexing will work.  It only has to compute & access the exactly right memory location, but how that is done doesn't really matter.
Addressing and pointer arithmetic follow the same properties as in mathematics, namely that commutativity and associativity and distribution are applicable. Generally speaking, the compiler understands this.  It just has to use the right numeric value (as the final effective address in the accessing instruction) when referring to some desired element.
Also, addressing arithmetic for indexing cannot overflow as long as you're using proper data types for indexes & intermediates, and the memory is known to exist (i.e. has been properly allocated as global, local, or heap, and the access is to an element that is within the bounds of the array).

I think "best" meant "most efficient".  So when writing assembly, you want to find the most efficient way to get the right answer, no matter how you get there, with address math being no different from other integer math.  At least I hope that's what they meant.

@PeterCordes, yes, people often use "best" without criteria.  But let me ask, is most efficient always shorter code sequence?  If so then there's no tradeoff between short and fast, but if not...  I know that short is not generally the fastest across all processors and all code sequeces, but here we can restrict to x64 intel & amd..

Also, we should mention optimization, where a complex addressing calculation broken into multiple instructions, some of which may be able to be hoisted out of loops (or cse'd) whereas a complex addressing mode that does it all in one go maybe cannot be hoisted of of a loop.

On modern x86-64, LEA throughput and latency vary with addressing mode, e.g. on Skylake-family, having 3 components [base + index + disp8/32] means 1/clock throughput and 3-cycle latency.  Same as imul.  Otherwise it's 1 cycle latency with better than 1/clock throughput. (https://uops.info/).  So there can indeed be a tradeoff between throughput and latency, and also code-size especially with one imul vs. two leas.  The OP's second code block is optimal on Skylake and Ice Lake families; we can't avoid a scaled idx. Zen 4 takes 2 uops to do 3-component LEAs, but they're only 2c latency.
